# Angular CLI and TypeScript outDir

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular-cli

I've just worked through the Angular CLI Heroes tutorial [here](https://angular.io/tutorial).  I've followed all tutorials and completed the HTTP tutorial.

All great learning about Angular 4 and TypeScript but one thing that struck me throughout the course was the javascript being compiled into the src folder.  It would be nice if there was some "next steps" tutorial about packaging things up for a deployment - but that is potentially outside the scope of Angular.

I want to change this but not 100% sure on everything I need to do.

Ideally it would be to compile to separate folder and include all files necessary to run the website.

I've looked at the **tsconfig.json** file and added an `outDir` setting:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "../dist/app",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

When I run `npm start` the code seems to build to the dist folder, but when the application runs, all I get in the browser is `Cannot GET /`

I am missing a few things including index.html - but I don't know what files I need exactly.  So my questions are:

1. What files outside of my compiled app folder are required to run the website?
2. Can I modify the project files to achieve this using Angular CLI?

Answer (score 1):

@Andez,

Angular CLI should have taken care of all of this for you.  Take a look at [ng build](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build) and it should have taken care of your two questions.

1. ng  build will take care of this and the content specified in the "apps" key of angular-cli.json will be included in the dist folder
2. angular-cli.json is the file you need to modify to include all the artefacts you want in the dist folder.

Hope above points you in the right direction

SOJ

Comment: Are there any docs on the .angular-cli.json?  I want to know the settings available and the effect they have on things.

Comment: @Andez - probably this is what you are looking for: [Angular CLI config schema](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-cli).

Comment: @Andez - if this helps you or answers your question, then accept the answer because that is why people stick around on StackOverflow.

Comment: Hey @SOJ.  I'm still looking into things - to get an understanding more on webpack and typescript.  I put a comment on the other answer saying I created a new project - but yet that does not create any intermediate javascript files when I run.  My question is centred around why I get compiled javascript files in the src folder and how to prevent it - or output to a different folder.  I normally accept the answer once I get a conclusive answer and a better understanding.  So just bear with me whilst I get the understanding on the .angular-cli.json

Comment: @Andrez - take all time you need to get familiar with it.  It's fun after all.  If you are compiling with "*tsc*" - you may need to add command line argument to direct transpiled javascript to the "dist" folder or you use an npm script to save your fingers. "*ng serve*" may just be useful to you as well.

Answer (score 1):

To host your app you need the following:

1. Run `npm run build -- -prod` (it does the same as `ng build -prod` but it can be sometimes better because in this case you do not need to setup the angular CLI globally, e.g. this is good for CI builder). This will create a folder that is configured in `.angular-cli.json`. By default it is `dist` folder
2. Take this folder and put its content to the server's root

Ideally you should not change any of the settings apart from `.angular-cli.json`. Why? Because you need to be expert in Webpack, TypeScript configuration and many other things. Furthermore, the changes you would make will most likely be not supported by future angular-cli versions. Please check the project [wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories) and I am sure you will find answers to all of your questions / requirements.

This answer still does not cover your server configuration. You should have a 404 fallback there, most likely compression and caching, maybe some proxied endpoints. However this is a huge topic which is not connected to angular-cli.

Comment: I'm still learning TypeScript and everything else to do with modern web apps.  Are there any docs on .angular-cli.json - what settings are available and a description of each?

Comment: Also I created new app using `ng new --style scss --minimal`.  However this doesn't generate any javascript files whilst I run with `npm start`.  I'm now trying to figure out what is different between the projects.  I just need this better understanding of what is going on when I do things against different configurations